# Can't Install Pulseaudio on Debian

Tags: debian, apt, audio, pulseaudio, dependencies

Here we go again, more dependency issues for unknown reasons: this time installing `Pulseaudio` on `Debian 8.6 Jessie`.

**Output**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 5.0-13) but 7.1-2~bpo8+1 is to be installed
              Depends: pulseaudio-utils but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: pulseaudio-module-x11 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: rtkit but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Sources**

```
deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

**APT-Cache Policy**

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://repository.spotify.com/ stable/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=0.4,o=Spotify LTD,a=stable,n=stable,l=Spotify Public Repository,c=non-free
     origin repository.spotify.com
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/contrib Translation-en
 100 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=jessie-backports,n=jessie-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=non-free
     origin ftp.ca.debian.org
 100 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=jessie-backports,n=jessie-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=contrib
     origin ftp.ca.debian.org
 100 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=jessie-backports,n=jessie-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main
     origin ftp.ca.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.ca.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.ca.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=jessie-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.ca.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=8.6,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.ca.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=8.6,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.ca.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
     release v=8.6,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.ca.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures/screenshots of text. You can easily copy/paste it and format it as Code Sample, which is the curly braces in the editor.

Comment: Run `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get install pulseaudio`

Comment: @Thomas I can do this via `Nano` and `Terminal`? I'm on i3.

Comment: @GAD3R 0 updated / installed. I've also run `apt-get clean`

Comment: install it from backports :`apt-get -t jessie-backports install pulseaudio`

Comment: You've got a mixture of Jessie and backports. What are your pin preferences? (What does `apt-cache policy` say?)

Comment: @StephenKitt I got it installed using backports. Do you think the backports is an issue? I used it for nvidia-drivers. Will update post with policy.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `apt` is picking `libpulse0` from backports, so you need to install all of `pulseaudio` from there (as suggested by [GAD3R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/153195/gad3r)):

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install pulseaudio
```

Your pin preferences appear to be OK, and there shouldn't be any adverse effects from installing the package in this way.

Comment: So this should install correctly via `main` but apt was pulling some from backports, causing the dependency issues?

Comment: Yes. To figure out why, you'd need to figure out why it wanted to install the backported `libpulse0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
software-properties-gtk
```

Choose download from main server

```
apt update && apt-dist-upgrade
```

Then try again